# Divisor class group of $X$ and $X - p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $V$ be a projective variety in $\mathbb P^n$ and $X=C(V)\subset \mathbb A^{n+1}$  its affine cone.
Let $\bar X$ be the projective closure of $X=C(V)$ and let $P$ be the vertex of the cone.

Hartshorne says $Cl(\overline X) ≈ Cl(\overline X-P)$ where Cl is the Weil divisor class group. (Page 146, Ex. 6.3 (a))

Why is this true?
I know for any open set $U\subset \overline X$ we have a surjection from $Cl(\overline X) \to Cl(U)$.
Here $U$ is the open set $\overline X\setminus P$.

Why is the map an isomorphism?

Comment: 1) This is not true for all $V$ - you're missing a dimension assumption, and it matters. 2) What divisors could be in the kernel of your surjection? 3) You could probably cite this a little better - "Hartshorne says" is a little vague, considering the book is ~500 pages.

Comment: You're right. Dim V ≥ 1.

Comment: I've made some edits. Kindly check while I think about the kernel thing you asked

Comment: Well the kernel consists of those divisors of X that become linearly equivalent to some rational function when restricted to X-p. I'm not able to proceed.

Comment: Did you check the proof of proposition II.6.6 as hinted at in the problem statement? I think you'll find it enlightening.

Comment: That proposition helps to prove that $\pi^*$ is an isomorphism. But I was asking why the surjection (as stated in my question) is an isomorphism?

Comment: Your notation is confusing: you call $X$ what Hartshorne calls $\overline X$. You should stick to Hartshorne's notation.

Comment: I don't know the syntax to put the bar over X. Either way, can you tell me why that map in my question is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a scheme $Y$ satisfying condition $(*)$ on page 130 of Hartshorne and a closed subscheme $Z\subset Y$ of codimension at least $2$, the restriction group morphism
$Cl Y\to Cl (Y\setminus Z)$ is an **isomorphism**.
This is Proposition 6.5 (b), page133, which has a two line proof!
Apply to $Y=\overline X$ and $Z=\{P\}$.